# Debugging Heap Space Problems in Groovy/Grails Application using Quartz

Tags: grails, groovy, heap-memory, quartz-scheduler

I created a small application in Groovy/Grails that uses Quartz to execute a small job every 10 seconds. Now I have the problem that after several hours of running, the application crashes with a `org.quartz.JobExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space [See nested exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space]`.

Now I am trying to find the/one cause of that problem using the [Eclipse Memory Analyzer](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/). By finding "problem suspects", the analyzer shows this outcome:

```
Problem Suspect 1

3,926 instances of "groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass",
loaded by "org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsRootLoader @ 0x122e88b98" 
occupy 95,746,168 (33.69%) bytes. 

Keywords
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsRootLoader @ 0x122e88b98
groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass

--    

Problem Suspect 2

1,010 instances of "com.mongodb.DBApiLayer",
loaded by "org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsRootLoader @ 0x122e88b98" 
occupy 56,522,416 (19.89%) bytes.
These instances are referenced from one instance of
"org.codehaus.groovy.util.AbstractConcurrentMapBase$Segment[]", loaded by 
"org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsRootLoader @ 0x122e88b98"

Keywords
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsRootLoader @ 0x122e88b98
org.codehaus.groovy.util.AbstractConcurrentMapBase$Segment[]
com.mongodb.DBApiLayer
```

Is it normal to have that many instances of `ExpandoMetaClass` in a Groovy (and Grails) application or might that be a problem I introduced?

Regarding MongoDB: The application reads and writes many small items from the DB using GORM *and* directly with Gmongo. However, I already checked all connections and they properly close after some time. The approximate number of live threads is about 40. So I think the DB layer should not be the problem. Still, it takes a large part of the heap. Any ideas on that?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User @jonnybot suggested that problem could be caused by GMongo, and indeed he was right. I started a discussion with the creator of GMongo in which I created a small application that inserts something into a MongoDB collection every second to be able to replicate the problem. The application shows a large memory leak:

```
class MemoryJob {
    def concurrent = false
    static triggers = {
        simple startDelay: 5000, repeatInterval: 1000
    }
    def execute() {
        def mongoUrl = "mongodb://localhost:27017"
        def mongo = new GMongo(new MongoURI(mongoUrl))
        def db = mongo.getDB("memory")
        println new Date()
        db.getCollection("test").insert(['date':new Date()])
        mongo.close()
    }
}
```

The author of GMongo then suggested to reuse the DB connections instead of creating new ones on every request. Example:

```
class MemoryJob {
    def concurrent = false
    static triggers = {
        simple startDelay: 5000, repeatInterval: 200
    }
    static mongoUrl = "mongodb://localhost:27017"
    static mongo = new GMongo(new MongoURI(mongoUrl))
    static db = mongo.getDB("memory");
    def execute() {
        println new Date()
        db.getCollection("test").insert(['date':new Date()])
    }
}
```

And indeed, this resolves the memory leak I was suffering from.

As a **conclusion**: Do not create a MongoDB connection on every request, but instead reuse a single connection. While there seems to be a memory leak in GMongo anyway, it can be circumvented by reusing connections.

Hopefully, this helps somebody save some time.

Answer (score 1):

This may actually be an issue with the GMongo driver. There's [a thread in the gmongo Github](https://github.com/poiati/gmongo/issues/20) where a user with a similar environment has a remarkably similar issue.

Gmongo is the driver used by the the grails mongo plugin ([see this source](https://github.com/grails/grails-data-mapping/blob/master/grails-datastore-gorm-mongo/src/main/groovy/org/grails/datastore/gorm/mongo/bean/factory/GMongoFactoryBean.java)).

If you can, try using the MongoDB driver itself, instead of Gmongo or the Grails plugin it relies on.

As a workaround, and as a means of isolating the problem, you could try increasing your heap size; this is especially a good idea if you're currently deflating your heap size artificially.

```
export GRAILS_OPTS="-Xmx1G -Xms256m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m"
grails run-app
```

If the memory consumption plateaus at a certain point, you might stop getting out of memory errors. If not, upping your heap size should do little more than delay the inevitable. Tracking the time-to-crash relative to heap size would be a really helpful thing to report to the gmongo dev team.

Comment: Actually I am even using Gmongo myself without using GORM in between (also added that to question). Thanks for the link, I will look into this, however, it appears that this issue was never really resolved. I'm now thinking about replacing my Gmongo code by using the official MongoDB driver directly.

Comment: Ah, heap space is set to 2GB. After restarting, the application uses just about 400MB so that should not be a problem at all.

Comment: It looks like that's what the fellow with the same problem had to do.

Comment: I was able to solve the problem and put that into an answer :)